# Load App Images at Runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want my Android application to work with different skins. So what I plan is changing all the images and fonts I used in the application for different skins.

What is the best way for this? How can i init all imageviews with proper image resources?

P.S : I want to change the skin at runtime and don't want to restart the app.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

you can create a ThemeManager class where you can manage the themes

```
public class ThemeManager {

    static ThemeManager tmanage;
    int ThemeCode;
    int topBarBackground, bottomBarBackground, buttonBackground, textColor;
    ArrayList<ThemeWrapper> twrapper = new ArrayList<ThemeWrapper>();

    public static ThemeManager getInstance() {
        if (tmanage != null)
            return tmanage;
        else
            tmanage = new ThemeManager();
        return tmanage;
    }



    public void setThemeCode(int themeCode) {
        ThemeCode = themeCode;
        setBottomBarBackground(themeCode);
        setTopBarBackground(themeCode);
        setButtonBackground(themeCode);
        setTextColor(themeCode);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setTheme(ArrayList<View> v) {

        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            if (v.get(i) instanceof RelativeLayout) {
                RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) v.get(i);
                layout.setBackgroundColor(getTopBarBackground());
            }

            else if (v.get(i) instanceof Button) {
                Button layout = (Button) v.get(i);

                layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getShape(getButtonBackground()));
                layout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                layout.setTextSize(12);
            }

            else if (v.get(i) instanceof LinearLayout) {
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.get(i);
                layout.setBackgroundColor(getBottomBarBackground());
            }

            else if (v.get(i) instanceof TextView) {
                TextView layout = (TextView) v.get(i);
                layout.setTextColor(getTextColor());
            }
        }
    }

    private Drawable getShape(int col){
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR, new int[] { col,
                col, col});
        gradientDrawable.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        gradientDrawable.setCornerRadii(getRandomFloatArray());
        gradientDrawable.setGradientCenter(0.0f, 0.45f);
        gradientDrawable.setStroke(1, Color.WHITE);
        gradientDrawable.setSize(60, 30);

        return gradientDrawable;
    }

    private float [] getRandomFloatArray(){

        float[] floats = new float[8];
        for (int i =0; i < floats.length; i++){
            floats[i] = 2;
        }
        return floats;
    }

    public int getTopBarBackground() {
        return topBarBackground;
    }

    public void setTopBarBackground(int topBarBackground) {
        this.topBarBackground = topBarBackground;
    }

    public int getBottomBarBackground() {
        return bottomBarBackground;
    }

    public void setBottomBarBackground(int bottomBarBackground) {
        this.bottomBarBackground = bottomBarBackground;
    }

    public int getButtonBackground() {
        return buttonBackground;
    }

    public void setButtonBackground(int buttonBackground) {
        this.buttonBackground = buttonBackground;
    }

    public int getTextColor() {
        return textColor;
    }

    public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
        this.textColor = textColor;
    }


}
```

I was changing the colors for the views you can set the drawables as well now use this in your activities onResume function

```
private void changeColor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


ArrayList<View> v = new ArrayList<View>();
    v.add(topBar);
    v.add(bottomBar);
    v.add(updateBio);
    v.add(updateEvents);
    v.add(updateGallery);
    v.add(updatePersonalStyle);
    v.add(updateVip);
    v.add(updateStatus);
    v.add(NameLink);
    v.add(changeProfilePicture);

    ThemeManager theme = ThemeManager.getInstance();
    theme.setThemeCode(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
            getApplicationContext()).getInt("Theme_Color",
            Color.parseColor("#7606a5")));
    theme.setTheme(v);
}
```

just call this function in the onResume